WPF/XAML problem showing/hiding DataGridColumn based on DynamicResource
I have a WPF/MVVM (CommunityToolkit/MvvmLight) app where there are a number of DataGrid controls where I want to dynamically show/hide various columns based on a user's selection in a drop-down control.
The DataGrid columns are not auto-generated.
The visibility is defined in a ResourceDictionary like so:
<Visibility x:Key="unitQualityVisibilty">Visible</Visibility> 
The objects in the drop-down control have their own overrides of these Visibility items which are programmatically applied when the drop-down selection changes i.e.
foreach (var key in value.ResourceDictionaries.Keys)
{
    Application.Current.Resources[key] = value.ResourceDictionaries[key];
}

Here is an example where the Quality column should be shown or hidden based on that selection:
<DataGrid x:Name="units" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Details.Units}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" Header="Quality" Visibility="{DynamicResource unitQualityVisibilty}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Width="25" Grid.Column="1" Text="  v" FontSize="10" FontWeight="DemiBold" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource unitQualityConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="UnitQuality"/>
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.RuleSet" ElementName="units"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox e:ItemsSourceDecorator.ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.UnitQualities, ElementName=oob, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UnitQuality}" SelectedValuePath="Key" IsReadOnly="True" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<TextBlock Text="If you can see this UnitQuality Is Allowed" Visibility="{DynamicResource unitQualityVisibilty}" Grid.Row="1"/>

However, the Quality column does not change its visibility when the DynamicResource item changes.
To check that the override mechanism is working I added a TextBlock item whose Visibility uses the same DynamicResource (last row in the xaml above); and that does show/hide as required so I know that the basic mechanism is working, just not for DataGridColumns.
I can show and hide the column using a BooleanToVisibility converter but that relies on having properties on the drop-down control objects that govern whether the column is visible, and I was hoping to avoid that as there are multiple columns in different DataGrids that should be selectively shown/hidden.
EDIT...
having come across this SO article:
DataGridTextColumn Visibility Binding and thinking about my use of the TextBlock to demonstrate that the DynamicResource override mechanism is working correctly then I have a workaround:
If I set the height of the GridRow containing the TextBlock to 0 then it will be hidden on the UI. I then gave the TextBlock an x:Name of unitQualityVisibility and use the TextBlock's Visibility property in the DataGridColumn like so:
<DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" Header="Quality" Visibility="{Binding  Source={x:Reference unitQualityVisibility}, Path=Visibility}">

Not ideal but it works a treat..
